# Matching two images

Tags: java, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection

How can we match two images using Java. I want to make a face recognition application, that will store face of people at some location and then later will check whether a person is a member or not. If the persons face will match a pic already in database, then the person will be authenticated else not. Is there a way to do so.

Comment: Possible dplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182849/face-detection-in-java

Comment: @Mark A little harsh? It happens.

Comment: Just to be sure, we're talking about matching two different photographs of the same person, yes?

Comment: @Tony Ennis: No. It is possible that I may have 50 users with 50 pics. Now when a user wants to login, I will verify whether the user is a member or not by taking its pics and comparing it to all pics I have in database. If a match is found I will welcome the user else the access will be denied.

Comment: What you want to do is not possible to the extent that you can -with any certainty- decide if someone is a member of not just from a picture. You will be letting people in who are not a member, and keeping people out who are.

Comment: You tagged this face-detection but this is really a face recognition problem. Detection means "is there a face ?", recognition means "who is this face ?". Detecting faces is *almost* trivial these days. Getting robust recognition is still an active area of research.

Comment: @Koan: It wasn't me who tagged it as face detection. It was someone who edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

check this [thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5270630) for java related face recognition software. You will need to use the Java Advanced Imaging library, which is a pain, but it's doable.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do so. It is a well studied research problem. It is called face recognition in a gallery-probe setup. You should perhaps read [this article](http://www.face-rec.org/interesting-papers/General/zhao00face.pdf).